# PHP dir/file hierarchy with "include" and (dirname(__FILE__) . 'SOMETHING')

Tags: php, include, dirname

thx for your time and attention.

I'm working with a php site in which I want to integrate a guestbook I found on the net that works without mySql Database.

My site is structured like this:

```
host.../myDir/fileA.php (here we have all the basic files of the site)
```

The Guestbook first file I would integrate is located here:

```
host.../myDir/gbook/gbook.php
```

Under gbook dir there's another dir called template that contains everything needed for graphic (as obvious).

Inside fileA.php I had inserted this include command:

```
require_once "gbook/gbook.php";
```

And inside gbook/gbook.php there's this command:

```
$settings['tpl_path'] = './templates/'.$settings['template'].'/';
```

Now I've read php guide for (include(dirname(**FILE**). '...') and I've read also your multiple explanation about this command, so I've tested this:

```
 $settingsBase['tpl_basepath'] = (dirname(__FILE__) . '/');
 $settings['tpl_path'] =  $settingsBase['tpl_basepath'].'templates/'.$settings['template'].'/';
```

But is works for integration but not for graphic.
So this is what I'm not understanding and what I've understood.

When you "include" a file inside another file, the compiler reads the code as it's part of the same file.
That's the problem. When you include something that is located in another /dir the compiler gets the file, but not the whole structure so if there's another "include" inside included file, the compiler will look for it inside the /dir where is located the includer file. Correct?

So exist the dirname() command right?
I mean is it correct to use dirname() to tell the compiler that I want to include this file /dir/file.php and everything that will come after and it's included inside that included first file should maintain the same /dir structure?

So if there's this structure:

```
host.../myDir/fileA.php
```

and this file contain command:

```
include gbook/fileB.php
```

and this file contain command:

```
include /template/all_the_other_files.php
```

and the complete structure is:

```
(1) host...  
   (2) /myDir (where_there's_site)
      (3) /gbook (where_there's_base_gbook_structure)
         (4) /template (where_there's_template)
            (5) /others dir (where_there's_pics_smiles_etc...)
```

How can I tell to complier "hey when you include gbook/gbook.php" everything is included inside gbook.php will have to be found inside host.../myDir/gbook/...?

I know that probably it's really simple for you, but I'm trying to overcome the problem and I can't understand basic solution and explanation of the problem.

Thx.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would recommend to use **require_once** instead **include**. It raises an error in case the required file is not found, and you don't need to care about multiple includes.

I think you only need to use this in your gbook/fileB.php:

```
require_once __DIR__ . /template/all_the_other_files.php;
```

As you see, you can use the DIR magic constant in newer PHP versions instead of dirname(FILE). Using it, you can realize includes to relative paths pretty easy. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thx. Tested.
It doesn't work yet, but I think there a problem with __DIR__ command.

This command return the physical location of file right?
Probably that's why it doesn't find to file required.
Infact an echo check return this:
for book.php file<br/>
     `/membri/esimeconomytools/esdea/gbook/gbook.php (and it's found)`<br/>

for one required file:<br/>
     `/members/myName/myDir/gbook/templates/default/overall_header.php (and it's not found)`<br/>

but the file I need is here:<br/>
     `http://myName.host.org/myDir/gbook/templates/default/overall_header.php` <br/>

how can I do?

Comment: You need to distinguish between server paths and URLs. For included (or required) files in PHP you always need the server path. And yes, the DIR magic constant gives you the physical folder of the PHP file it is used in.

Comment: But why if I use DIR it says that can't find the file even if the path seems to be correct?

Comment: Well then there must be some kind of mistyping. It seems to me that in the second include the DIR is not correct. Must be with double leading and trailing underscore (hard to type this in this editor.)